# Scala idiom for comparing to java.lang.Long

Tags: scala

What's the Scala idiom for comparing a long literal with a boxed java.lang.Long? I've come up with

```
myLong == new java.lang.Long(42L)
```

but it looks dreadful, and I'm hoping there's some cute syntax I'm not aware of.

Comment: What about `myLong == 42L`?

Comment: @frank-s-thomas gives me a: _„Comparing unrelated types: LengthWord and Int“_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala `==` uses `.equals` method internally. So it does boxing-unboxing automatically. As @Frank S. Thomas said the working way is

```
myLong == 42L
```

Comment: Thanks. My IDE told me that wouldn't work - guess I shouldn't have believed it.

Comment: `someFile.length == 42L` results in _„Comparing unrelated types: LengthWord and Int“_ .